# Capture instance of PHP class and call an instance function from JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, combobox

I have a page that asks for a country code in a ComboBox, and I want it to load some other ComboBox with certain values that depend on the first one.

The secondary data should be loaded using a function inside a PHP class, whose instance I need to capture. I'm still not very familiar with AJAX and jQuery, so that's my problem.

My code is like this (I omitted the most obvious parts, of course):

**new.html**

```
<script src="findIDTypes.js"></script>
<form>
    <select id="country_id" onchange="findIDTypes(this.id)">
        <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
        <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**dbfunctions.php**

```
class DBConn {

    public function GetInstance($host = FALSE, $user = FALSE, $pass = FALSE) {
        static $_instance = FALSE;
        if ($_instance === FALSE) {
            if ($host == FALSE || $user == FALSE || $pass == FALSE) {
                // Error! Can't instantiate
            }
            $_instance = new DBConn($host, $user, $pass);
        }
        // OK!
        return $_instance;
    }

    public function findIDTypes($country_id) {
        // Returns array of value pairs (Code, Description)
    }

}
```

**findIDTypes.js**

```
function findIDTypes(value_to_search) {
  // ???
}
```

What I need my AJAX/jQuery (not sure which) function to do is:

1. Capture the instance of DBConn
2. Call the instance function "findIDTypes()" in the PHP class
3. Retrieve the array of (C,D) pairs and load them, one by one, on the secondary combobox

What exactly do I need to do to complete steps 1 and 2, if it's possible at all?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php and javascript are entirely different, and while you can use php to *generate* javascript code before the page is rendered, you cannot *call* php functions from javascript.

This is because php runs on the server, and javascript (which the exception of Node.js!) runs in the browser.

To solve this, you need to expose your php as an API using [HTTP GET or POST methods](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

**Steps**

1. Build your php page to accept [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) url query parameters or [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) parameters, in one form or another.
2. Decide upon a method of communicating your data on the server end back to your browser's javascript/ajax. For this, I highly recommend [json](/questions/tagged/json) for an innumerable number of [reasons](http://www.json.org/). It easily integrates with php via `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`, and javascript via `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`.
3. Once you've established your "API" as it were in php, you can easily use jQuery's [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send and retrieve data to your php. Since your example is relatively simple, it may be as easy as something like http://yoursite.com/?init=DBConn_GetInstance and handling the $_GET['init'] function, then outputting the results of your function.

Comment: So that means I should create a class, for example "DBAPI", and call my class "DBConn" from there?

Comment: You certainly could -- that architecture is up to you. You could also have a simple page to `include` DBConn, do something like `json_encode(array("result"=>$newDBConn->GetInstance));`

Comment: It was actually easier than I thought, thank you very much for your help!